# Quote marks in args for littler/docopt

Tags: r, bash, docopt, littler

I want to pass strings like `key="value"` to a littler script. In bash, I have `argtest.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $1
```

which I can call, preserving the quotes from the shell by backslashes, and I see them in the output:

```
$ ./argtest.sh x=\"1\"
x="1"
```

However I can't get args like that through littler/docopt. Here's my test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env r

doc <- "Usage: thing -t thing

-t --thing thing     some args
"

opt <- docopt::docopt(doc)
print(opt$thing)

target = 'x="1"'

if(opt$thing==target){
    message("Winner")
}else{
    message("Loser")
}
```

Simple backquoting as in the shell example doesn't work:

```
$ ./argtest.r -t x=\"1\"
[1] "x=1"
Loser
```

And everything else I've tried also fails. Like:

```
$ ./argtest.r -t 'x=\"1\"'
[1] "x=\\1\\"
Loser
```

Can anyone be a winner here?

Answer (score 2):

I think this wants to be an issue ticket over at the [docopt repo](https://github.com/docopt/docopt.R).

As I recall, Jenny once had a corner case too.  Methinks that docopt deparses the arguments so thoroughly that you cannot (easily) protect the spaces otherwise used as demarcation.